Invalid bundle structure. The “xxxxxxxxMobileApp.app/libxamarin-dotnet.dylib” binary file is not permitted. when publish .Net MAUI to App Store
I'm having trouble publishing my app to the App Store via Transporter:
Asset validation failed (90171)
Invalid bundle structure. The “xxxxxxMobileApp.app/libxamarin-dotnet.dylib” binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: 1d9c85be-561e-48e5-873d-a24aa4baab52)
Asset validation failed (90171)
Invalid bundle structure. The “xxxxxxMobileApp.app/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.dylib” binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: ac5561b0-7128-4f50-afaf-09b0d8d6432b)
Asset validation failed (90171)
Invalid bundle structure. The “xxxxxxxMobileApp.app/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.dylib” binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: 0fe9a190-8d92-4612-a33d-2300f4b42df2)
Asset validation failed (90171)
Invalid bundle structure. The “xxxxxxxMobileApp.app/libSystem.Native.dylib” binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: cbf2f7fa-998b-492e-9910-814f80388e41)
build my app by command:
dotnet publish -f:net8.0-ios -c:Release -p:ServerAddress=MacIP -p:ServerUser=UserName -p:ServerPassword=UserPassWord -p:TcpPort=58181 -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/UserName/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/ -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=true

Download.Net 8.0 SDK for Mac and install it on Mac.

I was struggling with the same problem for hours. In the end, deleting the bin, obj and .vs folder as well as restarting both my development machine and the remote Mac (for good measure) solved the issue for me.
Classic Visual Studio moment.
